# Moving along individual origin does not work

Tags: modeling

There is such a geometry. I wanted to move all the selected vertices to the top relative to their normals to get a pointed shape.
[image]

And so I use normal motion + mode individually for each vertex. as you can see, the geometry is tilted from above. How do I complete my task?
[image]

Comment: Depending on the edges positions relative to the objects origin, you might be able to get away with selecting those edges and simply "scaling up" (changing transformation orientation to _Normal_ may assist with this). You can probably get the end result to look "pretty close" if that's what your after, however any sense of "specificity" may be lost (again, depending on the shape and the edges location relative to the origin). More of a quick, easy fix than a real answer, I admit.

Comment: From what I understand, individual origins does not work for vertices. For polygons or edges only.

Comment: Contiguous vertices are not considered as individual elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @lemon says.. connected vertices are not individuals. If you do the crazy thing .. every even vertex, followed by every odd vertex, it works.

But here, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (Shrink / Fatten) instead.